# How to get LSB bit in MIPS?

Tags: mips

Is there a short way to check/get for least significant bit in a 32-bit integer, in MIPS? It is obviously set for the odd numbers and an algorithm which checks for the whole number is odd or even can decide for this. But I just wonder is there a better way to do this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`andi $t0, $s0, 1` will get the least significant bit of `$s0` and put it in `$t0`.

Comment: good answer, additionally a more supplemental explanation can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531623/least-significant-bit-mips